# Adding content to a table row (<TR>) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic

I have a table as follows:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>col 1</td><td>col2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="insert">
   <td>field</td><td>Field 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>another field</td><td>one more field</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Now the issue is that I need to dynamically insert new rows AFTER the middle row (id = insert). I have a custom javascript function to insert elementsAFTER an element by using an insertBefore call on the next element.

The new rows create successfully using the following javascript:

```
var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
new_row.innerHTML="<td>test</td>";
insertAfter(document.getElementById("insert"), new_row);
```

However, the new row refuses to accept any simple html formatting using the innerHTML. The final output of the new row looks something like:

```
<tr>test</tr>
```

You see it doesn't want to output the  I have specified. The actual script is a lot more complex and so unfortunately manually adding each  using an appendChild or similar function would be far too time consuming and probably rather resource intensive. Is there anyway I can just add a 'chunk of html' to this table row and in this chunk define the table columns?

I'm baffled, any help is MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the native `insertCell()` method to insert cells.

Give this a try:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VzTJa/

```
var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
new_row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "test";
new_row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "test2";
```

or you can accomplish it without your `insertAfter()` function by using `insertRow()` as well.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VzTJa/1/

```
var insert = document.getElementById("insert");
var new_row = insert.parentNode.insertRow( insert.rowIndex + 1 );
new_row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "test";
new_row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "test2";
```

---

Give this workaround a try:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VzTJa/2/

```
var temp = '<table><tbody><tr>';
var close_temp = '</tr></tbody></table>';
var temp_div = document.createElement('div');


var html_to_insert = '<td>tester</td><td>tester</td>';

temp_div.innerHTML = temp + html_to_insert + close_temp;
insertAfter(document.getElementById("insert"), temp_div.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild);

temp_div.removeChild(temp_div.firstChild);
```

Basically creates a couple strings representing the opening and closing tags of a table. You concatenate it with your content, and set it as the `innerHTMl` of a temporary `div`, then fetch the row you want, and do an `.appendChild()`.

There may be a better way, or you may find a way to improve this one.

I came up with this after glancing at a solution in [this article](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html) from a guy who apparently worked on IE and is partly responsible for the parser.

Comment: You're right, I probably could add each cell independently but as I mentioned, the actual HTML is far more complex and it would be so much easier if I could add it in one go. The HTML that needs to be inserted is actually returned by a PHP script, so I'd need to edit that too to return each cell separately which is another cause for a headache.

Comment: @Michael: I see. If I remember correctly, there are some issues with `innerHTML` on `table` elements (in some browsers). I don't remember what the workaround is, but I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @Michael: I think I've got a workaround for you. I'll add it in a minute. I'll also post an article from the guy at MS who apparently implemented `innerHTML` in IE. Interesting read. The solution is based on the quick look that I took at his. You may prefer his.

Comment: dw: Thanks for your help! That solution works! I wonder how I never thought of it myself. Really appreciate your hard work, and thought it was worth mentioning that I can also add a few more table rows with this logic which prior to this I was contemplating disregarding because of the complexity. Once again, thanks!

Comment: document.createElement('tr') vs insertRow which one is better of inserting 1000 rows

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jQuery, try the append method from it. [jQuery append reference](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

If you do find performance to be an issue, you might find an improvement by building up the dynamic DOM you want to add in javascript *before* appending it to the actual HTML DOM element that will make it visible. This will keep your number of repaints to a minimum.

Comment: jQuery IS an option, however, this is a one off script I'm using, and so I'd really like to do it with native javascript rather than import a library for just one simple task. I will give this is a shot if nothing else works.

Comment: This code should work for you: `document.getElementById("insert").parentNode.insertBefore(new_row, document.getElementById("insert").nextSibling);` It may look odd, but give it a shot and I think you'll be presently surprised.