# How can I add new rows to a table without loosing data and with different name?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add new rows to a table but i want to put in those rows 3  inputs with diferent names, for example input_1, input_2 ...

```
<table class="tdatos" id="tabla">
<tr>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
    <th>Precio/Ud</th>                  
</tr>                               
    <td><input name="a_1"></td>
    <td><input name="b_1"></td>
    <td><input name="c_1"></td>
```

Más

and here my javascript function:

```
function masFilas(){        
var texto = ""
    for (i=1;i<3;i++){
        texto= texto + "<tr><td><input class='cant' type='text' size='4'></td><td><input size='100' type='text' ></td><td><input type='text' size='6'></td></tr>"
            }           
    document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML  = document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML + texto ;  
    }
```

I want to those inputs have a different name like a_1 , a_2 , a_3 
The other problem is that I loose the text I write in those inputs when I press the 'mas' button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding content to a table row (<TR>) with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789923/adding-content-to-a-table-row-tr-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will alter the inner html of the tables the value you type in input type will not be persistent so you need to add rows run time with the help of

```
tableObject.insertRow(index);
```

Detail example is on

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/